# Multiple Typescript declaration with incremental name

Tags: typescript

Do you know if there is a way to declare multiple variables which have the same prefix and a number in one line? By exemple for:

```
interface test {
  variable1: string;
  variable2: string;
  variable3: string;
  variable4: string;
  variable5: string;
  ...
  variable100: string;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design; better to have an array to store that kind of information.

Comment: Or, type `for (let i = 0; i < 101; i++) { console.log(\`variable${i}: string;\`); }` in the console, then copy and paste from the console to the interface...

Comment: are you sure what you need is not an indexed interface?

Comment: It's for GoogleAnalytics typings, and there is 200 variables named from `dimension1` to `dimension200`.